# Asp.net MVC web application and iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, asp.net

I am currently writing a web application in ASP.NET MVC, so far it is mostly a simple CRUD web app. The database is hosted on the cloud and I am using Entity Framework to interact with it.

I know that further in the development cycle we will have to make a mobile application (iOS with swift) which will interact with the same database, so I want to have a good framework that will be able to handle both without too much duplication of code or DAL, while still being secure.

Those are the options I have so far:

- Write my MVC web application and further down the line, make http requests to my controllers action from my app. Possible problems: Security and authentications of those calls?
- Write my MVC web application and a MVC Web API. Both my controllers of my web app and the iOS app will interact with this API. Possible problems: Will this setup work with the asp.net MVC web app?
- Write additional web methods in my MVC controllers specifically for the REST api call of my iOS app. Possible problems: Is it possible at all?

Comment: There's another option. Write a web application that's designed to work as an app on the phone. Often this is a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) or a hybrid SPA. Design your site to work [offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). Or deliver it via something like [Apache Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap). Write once, run anywhere!

Comment: It's hard to get these kinds of apps in Apple App Store as they normally get rejected as being nothing more that a website wrapper. Apparently they will reject any app that consists of just a WebView running a web app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend that you go the option of an API that both your `ASP.NET MVC` web application and the mobile application both talk to. Using `ASP.NET Web API` for this is a good choice, as it works well with both, current, consumers (`MVC` and `iOS`) that you have. `REST` is a very open standard and, as such, allows for a wide breadth of devices to connect to it; `ASP.NET Web API` was built with `REST` in mind.

A `JSON web token` (JWT) approach to security would also be wise, as that will allow you to support a wide array of devices (cookies are limited in that respect). You might want to consider using `OAuth` on your `ASP.NET Web API` in order to leverage open standards security and leverage authentication via third party (Google, Microsoft, etc.) if that is desired or feasible for your project.

Comment: In that case, I will have my data access layer and my business logic all inside my API? And my actual MVC application will only have the behavior logic and the UI?

Comment: You could do it that way or not. It depends upon if you want to have separate business rules in your web app versus your mobile app. Generally, but not always, web APIs serve data and the client/consumers determine there usage of that data.

Comment: Ok, it helps a lot to understand where I need to go with this project. Thanks!

Comment: @KarlAnderson - What is the best way to propagate the Identity through to the Web API? I am planning to build an iOS app for my website, and I know that the best way to do that is to separate my website out into the MVC front and API back, I figured how to do most things but I am struggling with how to handle the security through the layers. I've got the local login as well as OAuth. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!